# Casting anomaly with protocol types in Swift

Tags: swift, casting, protocols

I am experiencing what appears to be a casting anomaly when working with instances of a class and its subclass, both typed as a protocol to which the class conforms.

As I do not want to complicate the issue with specifics of my domain, I have given below an artificial example that illustrates the seeming problem.

```
protocol P {
    func canCast(_ p: P) -> Bool
}

extension P {
    func canCast(_ p: P) -> Bool {
        return p as? Self != nil
    }
}

class X: P {}
class Y: X {}

let a: P = X()
let b: P = Y()
```

Since `Y` is a subclass of `X`, we should be able to cast `b` to `X` but we should not be able to cast `a` to `Y`.

This works fine, as shown below:

```
print(a as? Y != nil)   // prints false
print(b as? X != nil)   // prints true
```

However, when I use the `.canCast()` method declared in the protocol, both the casts appear to succeed:

```
print(b.canCast(a))     // prints true
print(a.canCast(b))     // prints true
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from the answer posted by @meggar, I did some more work and discovered that `Self` in this situation always represents the type that conforms to the protocol and not any of its subclasses, regardless of whether the method is called on an instance of the conforming class or any of its subclasses.

Therefore, in this case,

```
return p as? Self != nil
```

is the same as

```
return p as? X != nil
```

This cast will succeed for instances of `X` as well as instances of any subclass of `X`, which is why `true` is returned in both cases presented in the question.

To prove this, I added a line to the method body in the protocol extension to print the type of `self` as well as the type represented by `Self`. I also created a new class `Z` which is a subclass of `Y`.

The full modified code is given below, which shows that `Self` continues to represent `X` regardless of whether the method is called on an instance of `X`, `Y` or `Z` (which is the type of `self` in each case).

```
protocol P {
    func canCast(_ p: P) -> Bool
}

extension P {
    func canCast(_ p: P) -> Bool {
        print("Type of self: \(type(of: self)), Self represents: \(Self.self)")
        return p as? Self != nil
    }
}

class X: P {}
class Y: X {}
class Z: Y {}

let a: P = X()
let b: P = Y()
let c: P = Z()

print(a.canCast(b))
// Type of self: X, Self represents: X
// true
print(b.canCast(a))
// Type of self: Y, Self represents: X
// true
print(c.canCast(a))
// Type of self: Z, Self represents: X
// true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return p as? Self != nil
```

is the same as

```
return p as? P != nil
```